# how to write DDL sql for create table in JPA

Tags: jpa

I want to use JPA to create tables  automatically by persistence.xml setting, but i found each sql must write in a single line and there must not have a semicolon just like below:

**The first situation** dose not work(because the code is not in a single line manner)

```
create table student(
   id Integer, 
   name varchar2(50)
)
```

The Second situation dose not work neither(because a semicolon added at the end of the sql sentence):

```
create table school(id Integer, name varchar2(50));
create table student(id Integer, name varchar2(50),school_id Integer);
```

The SQLs listed below are correct(which have not semicolons in each line end, and every line is a standalone sql),but  create a table SQL in a single line should not be friendly to read and maintain.  Is anybody know a better way to resolve this issue?

```
create table school(id Integer, name varchar2(50))
create table student(id Integer, name varchar2(50),school_id Integer)
```

Comment: Some JPA providers (e.g DataNucleus) allow you to put DDL (in provided input scripts) on multiple lines. Your chosen JPA provider is the problem, so the minimum you should do is tag this question for whichever provider you are using (and report a BUG on them)

Comment: Do you want JPA to automatically generate DDL for your entities? Or do you want to execute some additional SQL statements when your persistence context is initialized?

Comment: The eclipselink i just chosed, and the application server is glassfish.